# Starting Cassandra with docker gives error

Tags: cassandra

While starting cassandra with the below command, gives the error as

> docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase. See 'docker run --help'.

```
docker run -e DS_LICENSE=accept --memory 4g -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH="GossipingPropertyFileSnitch" CASSANDRA_DC="testDC" CASSANDRA_RACK="testRack" DS_LICENSE=accept --memory 4g --name cassandra -d datastax/dse-server -g -s -k -v /Users/test/cassandranode01:/var/lib/cassandra
```

Below is my repository screenshot

[image]

Please assist me on this.

Comment: did you try by replacing `--name Cassandra`  with `--name cassandra`

Comment: Yes, I tried with that. I did not work.   If I remove all the params and try with simple command as "docker run cassandra" it is working.  But I would was trying to work with the params for DC and rack, which is not working

Answer (score 0):

could you try using a specific version tag of DSE like 6.7.8? Latest tag is not working anymore.

Like this

```
docker run -e DS_LICENSE=accept --memory 4g -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH="GossipingPropertyFileSnitch" CASSANDRA_DC="testDC" CASSANDRA_RACK="testRack" DS_LICENSE=accept --memory 4g --name cassandra -d datastax/dse-server:6.7.8 -g -s -k -v /Users/test/cassandranode01:/var/lib/cassandra
```

Comment: No, It didn't work. Getting the same error this changed as well